# How can I disable HTML5 form validation in Angular2 apps?

Tags: html, validation, angular, typescript

I have a form that contains an input of type email that is required. I would like to have my own custom validation on that input field in order to be able to show the error message in different languages. However, currently the input field is evaluated by the HTML5 validation.

The code looks like this:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="user.email" type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required placeholder="{{'Email'|translate}}">
```

Is it possible to disable that, so that I am able to implement my own validation?

The validation code is yet to be written.

Comment: Include <form> tag with no validate attribute

Comment: import only { FormGroup, FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms';

Comment: @Aravind thanks, I will accept it as correct answer if you want to post it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Include  tag with no validate attribute as below

```
<form action="Form" novalidate>
  <input [(ngModel)]="user.email" type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required placeholder="{{'Email'|translate}}">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```